# Putting Artifactory behind SSL

Tags: artifactory

I manually installed Artifactory(V 2.6) on my centos and am using it with its own standalone jetty container. I use artifactoryctl start to start it and now I can access it using `http://myhostname:8081/artifactory`.
What is the best and easy way to put this behind https now?

Note: It will be nice if I can have both http and https access.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Please upgrade to the latest Artifactory version.
2. Starting Artifactory 3, it comes with embedded Tomcat, please refer to the official Tomcat documentation on [how to configure SSL on Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).
3. Another option might be configuring Artifactory behind Apache or Ngnix HTTP servers. In this case, Artifactory user guide provides documentation on how to configure ssl [for the former](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Apache+HTTP+Server#ApacheHTTPServer-SettingUpApacheHTTPS) and [for the later](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/nginx).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to answer my question. I cannot upgrade it yet due to java 1.7 dependency.

Comment: In this case, [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL) should help.

Comment: Thanks! I generated a keystore using keytool and set the keystore in jetty.xml file. It works fine and am able to access the site using https and port 8443.Can I ask you another question related to this?I am trying to connect to the same https URL through aritfactory plugin in Jenkins and I get a ""Error occurred while requesting version information: peer not authenticated" error. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Looks like the keystore used by Artifactory is not recognized by Jenkins? If you think that is the reason too, do you know how to make Jenkins recognize Artifactory keystore?

Comment: Putty Artifactory behind a proxy, like Nginx does introduce few important problems regarding uploading huge files (like ISO images). Nginx will always cache the entire uploads before sending them to the backend service, which means that you need to have a lot of space in `/tmp`